# Compiling JNI Example

Tags: java, java-native-interface, cygwin, sample

I am trying to use JNI to call a Java program from a C++ program. A supplier has put in place some phone apparatus and it only uses C++. I want to write a Screen Popper but don't want to do it in C++ so therefore want to pass across the event of the phone call coming in and the number to a Java routine to handle. I am using Netbeans as it makes the coding easier (usually!). I have not done C++ before which is why I want to escape to Java ASAP!

I am following instructions here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html
Which seem to set out how to call a Java routine from C++ but I cannot get it to compile. I have got as far as I with lots of help from this site but now I'm stumped.

I have added the '-D__int64=long long' switch to the compiler options for the project and added the Java libraries to the Application include paths. I have reparsed the code using code assistance. But now I'm left with this error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/f/Javadev/Sample2'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/sample2.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/f/Javadev/Sample2'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o.d
g++.exe -D__int64=long long   -c -g -I/cygdrive/C/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Java/jdk1.6.0_33/include/win32 -I/cygdrive/C/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Java/jdk1.6.0_33/include -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o main.cpp
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:65: recipe for target 'build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/f/Javadev/Sample2'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:58: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/f/Javadev/Sample2'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
g++: error: long: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

All source files are under F:\javadev, Sample2 is C++ and Sample3 is Java. Is there something else I need to include from Cygwin? It seems to say there is a problem with 'long' but that only really occurs in the switch and without it it fails even more catastrophically, saying that __int64 does not have a type.

Comment: I assume you did `-D__int64="long long"` as the argument has a space in it.

Comment: If you have a DLL that you can call, I'd advise to use JNA rather than JNI.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have now entered the switch exactly as you have suggested, it has fixed that issue, and exposed more. The code included 'not' as a variable name (fixed) and this line :

Comment: options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
I'm going to research this as well but if anyone could suggest a JNI tutorial / example of C++ calling Java that actually works with current versions I would be very grateful.

Comment: The above was just a warning and corrected by putting a space in after the -D. Now there is an error:
main.cpp:30:21: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEnv'
     {   mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "intMethod", "(I)I");
Which is a bit more complicated. Again, if anyone knows of a working JNI example I would be veru interested.

Comment: OK, changed all the (*env) references to env as it looks like the code is for C not C++ (although it has a C version as well and says this is C++). There is a warning left about the -D java... line and this error stops it compiling:
/cygdrive/f/Javadev/Sample2/main.cpp:25:(.text+0x5f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/sample2.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2